# How to decode H.264 HL with ffmpeg programically?

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, decode, h.264

I'm going to decode H.264 HL with ffmpeg library on iPhone.

There aren't any samples decoding with ffmpeg programically.

Who have a ffmpeg sample code decoding any codec?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `ffplay.c` file into the ffmpeg's source code. This is kind of the sample code for using the library.

Regards,
Alexandre